# MySQL correlated subquery SUM() ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, subquery, correlated-subquery

Is there anyway to optimize the following query:

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  (SELECT SUM(col1) FROM table_name_two t2 WHERE t2.name LIKE CONCAT('%',t1.name)) AS col1_count
FROM
  table_name_one t1
ORDER BY 
  col1_count DESC
```

Using `ORDER BY col1_count DESC` takes a long time.

Thanks.

Comment: SubQueries are very slow, I wouldn't recommend them. Can you LEFT JOIN these tables?

Comment: Your wildcard match is going to kill you. A wildcard at the front of the string is unable to use any index so it will table-scan to find every single match. And there's nothing you can do to fix it unless you redesign your data to put the matching parts of strings on the front.

Comment: @BookOfZeus: "SubQueries are very slow" --- I wouldn't ever say in such way. There are cases when subqueries are better than joins.

Comment: @le dorfier: I agree with you. In addition, if you have very low data volume maybe yes but if you have a large amount of data yes, specially if you use wild card in the where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a normal join with your comparison in the join's `on` clause:

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  SUM(t2.col1) AS col1_count
FROM table_name_one t1
LEFT JOIN table_name_two t2 on t2.name LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.name)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

It should be *way* faster this way - it's basically one query instead of "n" queries, although it won't get any help from indexes using the `LIKE` operator with a leading `%`